# Stack not aligned even when using only 4 byte values

Tags: x86, exploit

OK this has been bothering my for a while. I have a x86 binary which I'm supposed to attack via ROP. I already have all the offsets I need which I will show you in a minute.

I know that I need 44 bytes to overwrite the address of EIP, I also have the address of the system function and also the address of the string "/bin/cat" to use as an argument. Here's what my payload looks like:

```
payload = flat( asm('nop') * eip_offset) # eip_offset = 44
payload += p32(system_addr) # address of system
payload += p32(bincat_addr) # address of /bin/cat flag.txt
```

now if I send this to the application it just crashes, HOWEVER if I add a 4 byte padding like so:

```
payload = flat( asm('nop') * eip_offset)
payload += p32(system_addr)
payload += b"CCCC" # padding
payload += p32(bincat_addr)
```

it works. Can someone explain me why? I suspect that this has something to do with stack alignment but and don't know how it all connects? I'd expect this to execute "system("CCCC")" instead.

Comment: Without a binary is hard to tell. But your ROP chain doesn't call `system`, it *returns* to it. It's like a jump. So, assuming 32-bit code with no fast call conventions, you need to fake the return address for `system`. This is needed to make `system` find its parameter at the right address. In general, always emulate a call to a function properly (e.g. by including a return address on the stack).

Comment: @MargaretBloom you're right! I was a little confused about the stack layout but your comment made everything clear. I was forgettig the fake return address